# Spotfire Merging Tables - Preserving Order

Tags: r, spotfire

I am attempting to add a column from one table to another.  I can't use a simple join because the data type of the column changes, so I am using a data function/r-script to add the specified column.

I can get the proper column to populate, but cannot get the order to preserve (i.e. the incorrect records are being returned for a given identifier PROPNUM).

```
# join tables to ensure proper number of records
newTable <- merge(OutputTable, InputTable, by = "PROPNUM")

#populate column with values from merged table
OutputColumn <- newtTable[,4]

#sample output - output column is not order preserved
PROPNUM   OutputColumn
A         B
A         B
C         A
C         A
B         C
B         C
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order to be as the input table

```
# sort newtable 
newTable <- newTable(order(newTable$column1, newTable$column2, newTable$....))
```

Merging (or joining) does not preserve the input orders.